# PHP not getting parameters

Tags: php, url, get

I acces my page passing some parameters through the URL:

> www.mypage.com/page.php?aID=4091cdcd-773d-4ca5-bab2-41e1188870a9&sID=1_MX4yMjI1MTgxMn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIERlYyAyNiAwOTo1MDoyNiBQU1QgMjAxMn4wLjg1MjA4MTF-&nam=Gab&tel=7777777777

then in my PHP code I have:

```
if(isset($_GET['sID'])) {
    $sID = $_GET['sID'];
}
if(isset($_GET['aID'])) {
    $aID = $_GET['aID'];
}
if(isset($_GET['nam'])) {
    $nam = $_GET['nam'];
}
if(isset($_GET['tel'])) {
    $tel = $_GET['tel'];
}
```

I have no problem retrieving `$nam` and `$tel`, but `$aID` and `$sID` always get an empty string.  I have tried using double quotes `(isset($_GET["aID"]))` , but it has not made any difference.

Are there illegal characters on the string or a limit in size of a variable you can pass through the URL?  How can I GET variables `$aID` and `$sID`?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myTable (ArchiveID, SessionID, Name, Tel) VALUES ('$aiD', '$siD', '$nam', '$tel' )";

echo $query;
```

Echo $query's output is:

> INSERT INTO myTable (ArchiveID, SessionID, Name, Tel) VALUES ('', '', 'Gab', '7777777777' )

Comment: Show us the result of `print_r($_GET);` You also have an error on your last `if` (should be `$tel = $_GET[tel];`)

Comment: What do you see when you var_dump $_GET?

Comment: @njk, actually it's a notice: undefined index.

Comment: print_r($GET) = Array ( [aID] => 4091cdcd-773d-4ca5-bab2-41e1188870a9 [sID] => 1_MX4yMjI1MTgxMn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIERlYyAyNiAwOTo1MDoyNiBQU1QgMjAxMn4wLjg1MjA4MTF- [nam] => Gab [tel] => 7877556257 )

thanks njk for noticing that. fixed it on an edit.

Comment: @GabCas looks OK. Check for notices and typos.

Comment: What aID and sID appear to have in common is hyphens in the value.

Comment: @GabCas: Instead of pasting the variable dump in a comment, please go back and edit the original posting and paste it in there so it's readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) ***<<<--- Before you do anything else, read this first, understand it. It resolves your problem and tells you something very important about how to handle data in your software.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing your URL, I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [aID] => 4091cdcd-773d-4ca5-bab2-41e1188870a9
    [sID] => 1_MX4yMjI1MTgxMn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIERlYyAyNiAwOTo1MDoyNiBQU1QgMjAxMn4wLjg1MjA4MTF-
    [nam] => Gab
    [tel] => 7777777777
)
```

Therefore, I'm not sure what you mean by you're getting an empty string. You did have a typo in your code, where `$tel` references `$_GET['aID']`. I would advise you verify your code.

I would recommend that you also use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to verify that your script is using `GET`.

**Update**

Per your updated query, it seems as though your case is incorrect. **The variable name is case-sensitive.**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('$aiD', '$siD', '$nam', '$tel' )";
                                     ^       ^
```

Should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('$aID', '$sID', '$nam', '$tel' )";
```

1. **You have to enable error reporting and logging to the highest level when you develop PHP**.
2. **You have to check return values of methods you call to see if they did what you thought they did. You have to look for more error information if something failed.**
3. **You have to look into prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.**

And yes, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Do not use it for new code.

Comment: I also added the next line of code where I construct a query with the variables and the 'echo' of that query.

Comment: I also edited it and put two equally important points next to parametrized SQL queries. @GabCas Enable error reporting and logging to the highest level when you develop. PHP tells you about most of these mistakes on it's own. Then you don't need to stab in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

You notice in your sql statement you are not calling the variables you defined:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myTable (ArchiveID, SessionID, Name, Tel) VALUES ('$aiD', '$siD', '$nam', '$tel' )";
```

should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myTable (ArchiveID, SessionID, Name, Tel) VALUES ('$aID', '$sID', '$nam', '$tel' )";
```

and looks like njk updated his answer to reflect this so he should be credited for the answer.